# javascript, selected por Texto

Tags: javascript, jquery

Gostaria de selecionar `<selected=true>` com base no **texto** e não no **value**.
Tentei dessa maneira:

```
function setSelectBoxByText(eid, etxt) {
    var eid = document.getElementById(eid);
    for (var i = 0; i < eid.options.length; ++i) {
        if (eid.options[i].text === etxt)
            eid.options[i].selected = true;
    }
}
```

Basicamente tenho um DropDownList que ao selecionar envia o parametro para um IFRAME e este executa uma consulta que me retorna a palavra chave, com essa palavra chave quero deixar selected um outro DropDownList
O iframe retorna:

```
<script type="text/javascript">parent.document.setSelectBoxByText('DDL_CategoriaMega','Casa');</script>
```

Mas não esta funcionando.

Detalhes das páginas
Exemplo:
Página que chama o iframe

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function MudaDDLMega(valor) {
        document.getElementById('IFRAME_TESTE').src = "/busca_categoria_MEGA.aspx?IDCat=" + valor;
    }
 function setSelectBoxByText(eid, etxt) {
            alert('tste');
            var eid = document.getElementById(eid);
            for (var i = 0; i < eid.options.length; ++i) {
                if (eid.options[i].text === etxt)
                    eid.options[i].selected = true;
            }
        }
```

**HTML**

```
 <select id="DDL_Categoria" onchange="MudaDDLMega(this.value)">
    <option selected="selected" value="">Selecione</option>
    <option value="204">Academia de Escalada</option>
    <option value="228">Academias</option>
    <option value="1">Alugados</option>
```

Campo que gostaria que mudasse com base nesse primeiro

```
 <select id="DDL_CategoriaMega">
    <option value="1">Apartamento</option>
    <option value="2">Casa</option>
    <option value="3">Casa em Condom&#237;nio</option>
    <option value="4">Ch&#225;cara  Fazenda  S&#237;tio</option>
    <option value="5">Flat</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Olhando por cima a função `setSelectBoxByText` parece estar certa... Imagino que tenha algo a ver com o iframe mesmo. Quando você executa `var eid = document.getElementById(eid);`, o `eid` é preenchido corretamente? Tente dar um `console.log` (ou um `alert`, sei lá), nos `eid.options[i].text`. As opções estão corretas?

Comment: é coloquei um alert('teste'); e ele nem aparece, pelo visto essa chamada via IFRAME é o problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Descobri a resposta, não sei se excluo esse post ou posto a resposta:

A resposta é:
na página que chama o iframe

```
function setSelectBoxByText(eid, etxt) {
            alert('tste');
            var eid = document.getElementById(eid);
            for (var i = 0; i < eid.options.length; ++i) {
                if (eid.options[i].text === etxt)
                    eid.options[i].selected = true;
            }
        }
```

e no iframe eu chamo:

```
<script type="text/javascript">parent.setSelectBoxByText('DDL_CategoriaMega','Casa');</script>
```